# Using Google Query to Return Rows With Errors

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

If I have a column similar to this:

```
column_name
"Foo"
"Bar"
#N/A
"Baz"
#N/A
```

How can I use the query function to return just the rows with #N/A as below?

```
column_name
#N/A
#N/A
```

I know this can be done with the `FILTER()` function, but I'm curious if there is a way to do this with the `QUERY()`

I've tried:

`=QUERY(A:A, "SELECT A WHERE A = '#N/A' ", 1)`

`=QUERY(A:A, "SELECT A WHERE A = """&NA()&""" ", 1)`

But with no success yet.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Comment: Your first formula works fine here

Comment: Humm you're right. I'll have to check my main sheet to see why the query was not working. I tested it again with both #N/A as a String, and as the actual error function and they are both returned. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
=query(A1:A9,"where A = '#N/A'")
```